# Problems uploading images to server using nextjs

Tags: image, server, upload, client

I'm trying to upload images from client to server (or another possible solution) using NextJS, but I cannot find any working API or something like that.

Another possible solution is images hosting (sorry my english).

Any help?

I cannot reach any solution :C